# File name pattern for ignore files in Mercurial

Tags: regex, mercurial, glob, tortoisehg, hgignore

I use TortoiseHg and I have folders structure, as below:

```
testSet1
     test1
          filesystem
                    input_1.obj
                    output_1.obj
          etalon_1.obj
          result_1.obj
     test2
          filesystem
                    input_1.obj
                    output_1.obj
          etalon_1.obj
          result_1.obj
     ......
     errors.txt
......
result.xml
```

I need to ignore only .obj files located in directories "testSetN/testN", but not in directories "testSetN/testN/filesystem".
I use glob pattern "*/*/*.obj" in .hgignore, but it doesn't work. Mercurial just ignores all .obj files in all directories (including "filesystem" directory). But if I use, for example, "testSet1/*/*.obj", then everything works fine. How can I do what I need?
It's not necessary for me to use only glob syntax. I would be grateful for any way.

Comment: adding any obj to your repo seems odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html#syntax

> Neither glob nor regexp patterns are rooted. A glob-syntax pattern of the form *.c will match a file ending in .c in any directory, and a regexp pattern of the form .c$ will do the same. To root a regexp pattern, start it with ^.

According to this, the glob `*/*/*.obj` will match `.obj` files inside the `filesystem` directory, because the glob is not rooted. So it matches those files by rooting the glob at `testSetN/`

If you have the prefix of `testSet` on all folders, you can use the glob `testSet*/*/*.obj`. This way, it will ignore `.obj` files in a subdirectory of a directory that begins with `testSet`. - it would also ignore `a/testSetX/testY/Z.obj` as well as `testSetN/testN/N.obj`

Mercurial will also let you manually add files that would otherwise be ignored according to .hgignore, so you could simply ignore all `.obj` files, or use your original glob of `*/*/*.obj` and `hg add` the files you want to track.

**Edit: adding regex as discussed in the comments.**

If you prefer regex, or don't have a pattern to root the glob at, you need to use a regex. The regex `^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\.obj$` to match any `.obj` file at exactly two levels from the repository root. That is:

- `^` to anchor the match at the root of the repository
- `[^/]*/` to match any first-level directory. That is any sequence of characters that does not contain the directory separator `/`
- `[^/]*/` again, to match any second-level directory.
- `[^/]*\.obj$` to match any filenames that end with `.obj`

Comment: "To root a regexp pattern, start it with ^." So, I tried to use regexp "^(.*/.*/.*)\.obj$", but it doesn't work too. Why?

Comment: Because `.` also matches the `/` in the path, so that regex will match any files that is at least two levels deep from root. Try matching `anything but /` instead of `any character`, i.e. `^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\.obj$`

Comment: Thanks. "^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\.obj$" works fine for me!